# XSD - Make an attribute required only depending of the parent tag

Tags: xsd, required

In my xml shema I can put the tag `<item>` inside 2 different parent like this :

```
<page>
   <item name="foo"/>
</page>

or

<page>
    <list>
        <item class="path/to/class"/>
    </list>
</page>
```

How can I say in my xsd, `name` attribute  is mandatory only when the direct parent is `<page>` ?

Comment: A locally defined `item` can vary per parent, even in XSD 1.0.

Comment: @kjhughes, is it a question or an affirmation ?

Comment: It is a statement intended to guide you toward using different local declarations of `item` to solve your problem.

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
<xs:complexType name="listItemType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
   </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="listType">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="listItemType" name="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="pageType">
  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="itemType" name="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```